# Using awk gsub with /1 to replace chars with a section of the original characters

Tags: awk

This is what I'm doing (I just want to get rid of the leading numbers in the fourth column)

```
cat text.txt | awk 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"} {gsub(/[0-9XY][0-9]?([pq])/,"\1",$4); print}'
```

This is my input

```
AADDC   4902    3   21q11.3-p11.1   4784    4793
DEEDA   4023    6   9p21.31|22.3-p22.1  2829    2832
ZWTEF   3920    10  8q21-q22    5811    5812
```

This is my Output

```
AADDC   4902    3   11.3-p11.1  4784    4793
DEEDA   4023    6   21.31|22.3-p22.1    2829    2832
ZWTEF   3920    10  21-q22  5811    5812
```

But I want this to be my output

```
AADDC   4902    3   q11.3-p11.1 4784    4793
DEEDA   4023    6   p21.31|22.3-p22.1   2829    2832
ZWTEF   3920    10  q21-q22 5811    5812
```

Comment: I don't think you can use the `\1` reference there. Which version of awk? Maybe you have `gensub()`?

Comment: I believe it's gnu awk. I ran "awk --version
GNU Awk 4.1.3, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.4-p1, GNU MP 6.1.0)
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2015 Free Software Foundation."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `GNU awk`, you can use `gensub` which, unlike `gsub`, supports backreferences:

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"} {$4=gensub(/[0-9XY][0-9]?([pq])/,"\\1",1,$4); print}' text.txt
```

Some explanations:

> What is the extra "\" for by the 1:

Because otherwise, that would be the character of ascii code 1.

> Why does 1 need to be placed between the \1" and the $4:

To tell `gensub` to replace only the first occurence of the pattern.

> Is there a reason why you must put $4= as well as $4

Yes, unlike `gsub`, `gensub` doesn't modify the field but returns the updated one.

Comment: All right thanks. What is the extra "\" for by the 1 and why does 1 need to be placed between the \\1" and the $4. 
.
And is there a reason why you must put $4= end as well as $4).